# Crash report on Developer console ... seems truncated

Tags: android, console

I am trying to view a crash report of my app on the android developer console ... it long and at the end of it, says "... 10 more" ... I cant view the rest, any ideas?

Thanks.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service
>   com.example.wb.filterService:     java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2595)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.example.wb.filterService.b(Unknown Source) at
>   com.example.wb.filterService.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com.example.wb.filterService.onCreate(Unknown Source) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2585)
>   ... 10 more

Comment: Usually, those lines are immaterial. In this case, you have no application code of your own in the calls prior to `handleCreateService()` on `ActivityThread`, and so the fact that you cannot see those 10 lines should not matter.

Comment: So am I right in thinking that the error (NullPointerException) is NOT due to me failing to declare or appoint a variable?  ... I am struggling to reproduce the error.

Comment: Your problem lies somewhere in `com.example.wb.filterService`. Beyond that, courtesy of ProGuard, I can't tell you more specifically where your problem lies. Failing to declare a variable will result in a compile error, and I do not know what it means to "appoint" a variable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I shall keep looking.  I am misusing terms here; I think I know what the issue is.  Thanks.